# jQuery Check if Element is in results of .prevAll() or .nextAll()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm essentially creating a wizard with tabs on a web app and tabs before the active one will be styled one way (in green) indicating completion, and tabs after it styled a different way to indicate not complete (in gray).

[image]

```
<div class="tabContainer">
    <ul class='tabs'>
       <li><a href='#tab1'><span class="badge">1</span></a></li>
       <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
       <li><a href='#tab2'><span class="badge">2</span></a></li>
       <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
       <li><a href='#tab3'><span class="badge">3</span></a></li>
       <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
       <li><a href='#tab4'><span class="badge">4</span></a></li>
       <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
       <li><a href='#tab5'><span class="badge">5</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In a custom function I'm writing called `setTab()`, I pass which tab I want to be active and then attempt to modify all other tabs to have styles indicated above.

```
function setTab(tabId) {

        var $active, $content, $links = $('ul.tabs').find('a');

        // Make tab active
        $active = $($links.filter('[href="#tab'+tabId+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $active.find('span').addClass('badge btn-info');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));

        // If Tab before, show as complete
        var previousTabs = $active.prevAll('a');
        previousTabs.removeClass('active');
        previousTabs.find('span').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('badge btn-success');

        // If Tab after, show as incomplete
        var nextTabs = $active.nextAll('a');
        nextTabs.removeClass('active');
        nextTabs.find('span').removeClass('btn-info').removeClass('btn-success');

        // Hide the remaining content
        $links.not($active).each(function () {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        // Show Content
        $content.show();
    }
```

**I'm looking for a way to check if an element is in the results of a `prevAll()` or `nextAll()` command in jQuery.**

I've tried to figure it out using `$.inArray` and `$.each` but haven't had much luck. I'm guessing the first didn't work because the result set is an object, not an array. And the second one doesn't work because I need to compare it to an element which isn't available inside the `$.each` function. I'm sure with enough tweaking I could figure that one out, but there has to be a better way.

What is the best way of determining whether an element exists before or after another element, and if it is using the `prevAll` and `nextAll` methods I've been attempting, how can I do a boolean match with that result set?

Comment: Look at `.is()`: http://jsfiddle.net/8h5Ew/1/

Comment: why not just do something like `activeTabBadge.prevAll().addClass('green');` ?

Comment: @JosephSilber Great point, I had no idea :) Hopefully we aren't using older than 1.7.2, but then again, people are still using IE6/7. I think you should keep your answer, I thought it was a great alternative

Comment: @jbabey, thats a really good idea. Let me try that.

Comment: And by the way, using `$.inArray`, you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cSe2J/ and check that it's not `-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of various answers, I made something work:

```
/**
* Set active tab and adjust other tabs in process
*/
function setTab(tabId) {

   var $active, $content, $links = $('ul.tabs').find('a');

   // Make tab active
   $active = $($links.filter('[href="#tab'+tabId+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
   $active.addClass('active');
   $active.find('span').addClass('badge btn-info');
   $content = $($active.attr('href'));

   // If Tab before, show as complete
   var previousTabs = $active.parent().prevAll('li').find('a');
   previousTabs.each(function(index, el) {
      $(el).removeClass('active');
      $(el).find('span').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('badge btn-success');
   });

   // If Tab after, show as incomplete
   var nextTabs = $active.parent().nextAll('li').find('a');
   nextTabs.each(function(index, el) {
      $(el).removeClass('active');
      $(el).find('span').removeClass('btn-info').removeClass('btn-success');
   });

   // Hide the remaining content
   $links.not($active).each(function () {
      $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
   });

   // Show Content
   $content.show();

}

setTab(3);
```

Looks like the DOM is what was messing me up...I needed to go up a level. Thanks for all the great answers!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `index`:

```
$('element').nextAll().index(el) != -1
```

Comment: What would `el` be in this case? The main selector is my active element. At runtime, I don't know which elements are returned by `nextAll()` so how would I know what to pass to `index()`?

Comment: I guess I don't understand your actual question then.  I thought you had some reference to an element already and you wanted to check if it existed in the results of `nextAll`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, disregard my previous comment. That was in the context of an `$.each` loop comparing the iterated element. I figured out a better way and added it to my question above.

Answer (score 2):

If you're passed the selected badge, you can avoid all of this by just marking all the previous badges as "completed". Something like:

```
var setTab = function (tabBadge) {
    tabBadge.prevAll('.badge').addClass('completed').removeClass('inProgress todo');
    tabBadge.addClass('inProgress').removeClass('completed todo');
    // ignore the addClass here if the gray badges are the default style
    tabBadge.nextAll('.badge').addClass('todo').removeClass('inProgress completed');
};
```

Note this functionality is very similar to [star rating plugins](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/), which is where the `prevAll` idea comes from.

Answer (score 1):

compare the native JS elements inside a loop :

```
var set  = $('element').nextAll(),
    elem = $('#someElement'),
    in_collection = false;

set.each(function() {
    if ( this === elem.get(0) ) in_collection = true;
});
```

or you can use `is()` to check if any elements inside a collection matches a selector:

```
    var set  = $('element').nextAll(),
    elem = $('#someElement'),
    in_collection = set.is(elem);
```

Comment: Or if the elements are already in jQuery objects (like in your first example), you could use `if (set.is(elem)) {}`

Comment: @Ian - that's true, is() accepts both selectors and elements, so that is a better example really.

Comment: It accepts many things! Haha either way, it really depends on what the OP already has to work with, because both my example and your old example work equally